# iPad App for iPad 4.2.1 no support

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

My actual iPad Application causes an Exception. I try to run it on a real device.
With the simulator for iPad 4.2. or 4.3. everything runs perfect. For  my iPhone it also runs (for building it for iPhone device of course).

My deployment target is 3.2.2 and i get the following exception during starting the application on the iPad:

```
> warning: Unable to read symbols for
> /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/4.2.1
> (8C148)/Symbols/usr/lib/info/dns.so (file not found). 2011-07-13
> 13:34:59.270 LocationRes[1667:307] *** Terminating app
> due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason:
> '[<UIApplication 0x130a30> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is
> not key value coding-compliant for the key view.'
```

I have no idea which setting in Xcode is set wrong.
...and i am using xCode 4.0.2.!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing wrong in Xcode settings, you tried to use KVC with a class that is **not** KVC compliant.

More info about KCV [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/KeyValueCoding.html)